# Mysql inserted id in the insert's value array

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm storing order in my table like this:

ID, NAME, ORDER

1, name_1, 1000

2, name_2, 2000

3, name_3, 3000

so basically:
ORDER = ID*1000

and what I do is after inserting row into this table like this

```
INSERT INTO table(name) VALUES('name_x');
```

I update order value in this row like this:

```
UPDATE table SET order = mysql_insert_id()*1000 WHERE id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Is there any other way to not make this into two statements? Like some magical mysql function ACT_ID()

so it would be like

```
INSERT INTO table(name, order) VALUES('name_x',ACT_ID()*1000);
```

Thanks in advance for all your responses.

Comment: If this is a fixed rule, why do you even have this in your database? Just use the ID when retrieving the record and multiply it by 1000. As it is now, your database contains the same information twice, which is redundant and pointless. :)

Comment: I get your point, you should not store any calculable data in the database. But the thing is if I want to move the object with id 3 between object 1 and object 2 - basically move it up one level, I update it's ORDER column to (1000+2000)/2. So the order of objects is now ID. ORDER. .. 1. 1000, 3. 1500, 2. 2000. If there's any other way of storing order of this data, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');
```

See MySQL Docs [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-usagenotes-functionality-last-insert-id.html)